# Shall I free/destroy exceptions after exception handling?

Tags: delphi, memory-management, exception

I'm debugging a delphi program.

```
except
    on e: TErrorTapeDrive do
        if e.errorCode = 1104 then
            if Assigned(indexDoneEvent) then
                indexDoneEvent;
        // other handling...
    // other handling...
end;
```

I catch an Excetion e and do what I need. Now, when the debug program counter reach the line just below `end;`, if I hover `e.errorCode` with the cursor, I can still see its value. I would expect this was out of scope and, eventually, destroyed.

So, my question is: shall I free/destroy exceptions after exception handling?

Comment: Please consider re-raising that exception in the case that the error code *isn't* 1104. Currently, your code *silently ignores* all other errors.

Comment: Not just errorCode, @RobKennedy, but also other types of Exceptions shall be handled.

Comment: No, Paolo. Your current code already *ignores* other exception types, which is the **correct behavior**. Never catch an exception unless you're writing code to *fix* the problem that caused the exception. If you can't fix it, then don't catch it; otherwise, code further up the call stack is *denied* the opportunity to fix it.

Comment: @RobKennedy Ok, I understand your point here! Very good advice!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The runtime takes ownership of exceptions after they are raised. You do not need to free them.

The exception is destroyed at the end of the block in which it is handled, as demonstrated by this program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  MyException = class(Exception)
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

destructor MyException.Destroy;
begin
  Writeln('MyException.Destroy');
  inherited;
end;

procedure Main;
begin
  try
    raise MyException.Create('Boo');
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Writeln('After try/except block');
end;

begin
  Main;
  Readln;
end.
```

which outputs:

```
MyException: Boo
MyException.Destroy
After try/except block
```

Whilst the debugger may still show you information about the exception after it has been freed, that behaviour is undefined. The compiler understands that the exception has left scope, even if the debugger is ignorant of that fact.

---

If you want an exception's lifetime to extend beyond the `except` block which handles it then you would need to call `AcquireExceptionObject`. Once you do that, it becomes your responsibility to free the exception whose lifetime you acquired.

Comment: Good the point of AcquireExceptionObject, cause it's in topic with the question.

Comment: The documentation of `AcquireExceptionObject` also points out that exceptions are reference counted and that it increases the ref count. `ReleaseExceptionObject` on the other hand decreases the ref count. When the ref count reaches zero the exception will be freed.

Comment: You normally don't care about that, since the compiler handles that for you, but as David says it's possible to manage the lifetime of an exception object beyond the exception block manually with these functions.

Comment: One common use case for manual exception lifetime management is when you wish to capture an exception raised in one thread, and re-surface it in a different thread. `TThread.FFatalException` is a good example of that.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler + RTL takes care of that for you, so don't.

As for the `e: Exception` object still beeing "valid" after the end of the except block, see this question:

[Why are Delphi objects assigned even after calling .Free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235033/why-are-delphi-objects-assigned-even-after-calling-free?rq=1)

Destroying something doesn't guarantee that the memory is immediatly invalidated, it just makes it available for reuse.